# Getting the latest file in shell with YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.csv.gz format

Tags: linux, shell, unix

1)I have set of files in a directory in shell and i want go get the latest file depending on the time stamp in the file name.
2)For Example:
`test1_20180823_121545.csv.gz`
`test2_20180822_191545.csv.gz`
`test3_20180823_192050.csv.gz`
`test4_20180823_100510.csv.gz`
`test4_20180823_191040.csv.gz`
3)
From the above given files based on their time and date extension. My output should be `test3_20180823_192050.csv.gz`

Comment: What did you tried so far? Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: Hey Luis sorry for that but I tried too but i haven't succeed. So thought of not giving some false code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` and `sort`:

```
find /path/to/mydirectory -type f | sort -t_ -k2,3 | tail -1
```

Option for the `sort` command are `-t` for the delimiter and `-k` for selecting the key on which the sort is done.

`tail` is to get last entry from the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

if files have also corresponding modification times (shown by ls -l) then you can list them by modification times in reverse order and get the last one

```
    ls -1rt | tail -1
```

But if you can not rely on this, than you need to write the script (e.g. perl). You would get file list to array then extract time stamp to other array, convert timestamps to epoch time (which is easy to sort) to other array, sort while sorting also file list. Maybe hashes can help with it. Then print last one. 
You can try to write it, if you will have issues, someone here can correct you.